# Can we delete from the same table based on some condition?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the query below, but it's indicating an SQL syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd1where d1.num='7' and time in (select time from dummy2 d 2 whe' at line 1 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Any suggestions?

Note here that the delete operation is executing with the same table.

```
delete from dummy2 d1 where d1.num='7' and time in (select time from dummy2 d2 where d2.num='5') ;
```

Comment: If you get an error message and if you ask about this error message it would make sense if you included the actual error message in your question.

Comment: *showing syntax error* Where is the error message? It's on the screen right in front of you. We can't see your screen from here. Please [edit] your post to include the **exact** error message you're seeing. You're asking for free help to solve *your problem* - it's in your best interest to give us the details you already have to make it easier for  us to give you that help. Also, *any suggestions?* is not an acceptable question here.

Comment: SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd1where d1.num='7' and time in (select time from dummy2 d 2 whe' at line 1
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Comment: thanks for your help,i got an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete i1.*
FROM dummy2 AS i1
JOIN dummy2 AS i2 ON i2.time = i1.time
WHERE i1.num='7' and i2.num='5';
```

Comment: This is the answer for the question asked by me above,which works for me